# Why wasn't I notified of a new privilege I got?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just reached 1k mark and got a privilege of seeing vote count I would like to request a feature so that the user is notified of the privileges they get so that they can use it in a better way.
I googled and was able to find out this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

What I really expect is at least like the vote change is notified similarly privileges should be.

Consider I figured to use review question when I reached 800 points must be a months period.So I could have gone through a lot of review questions already had  I been notified.This feature might not seem good to the ones having large
reputations but it will be helpful for community members like me who are trying hard to get good reps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you should have a message / event in your "achievements" drop menu each time you unlock a privilege.

Comment: I haven't got that anywhere.Both in inbox message and achievement dropdown I can post a screenshot here if you want @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: post a screenshot in your question, it won't hurt.

Comment: I've added both inbox and achievement screenshot as you can see I haven't received any notification @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: You mean you should get a notification for 1000 points? maybe you should wait until tomorrow. Sometimes (like badges) it takes time for things to be computed on SO. Do you have the privilege yet? where is the point where you went from 99x to 100x ? we cannot be sure.

Comment: I am having the privilege but didn't get any notification about it